# Mongoose create() gives 'Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object],[object Object]"' for a schema with Array

Tags: mongoose

Have a schema with following values:

```
var CartSchema = new Schema({
//...

requests: [{
        _id:false,
        type: String,   
        count: Number,  
        expiration: String
    }]

})
```

When I try to call mongoose create() with a valid requests object with a couple of requests I am getting the following error:

```
    message: 'Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object],[object Object]" at path "requests"',
    name: 'CastError',
    kind: 'Array',
    value: [Object],
    path: 'licenses' } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

After facing this on our system I could not find a solution on the net.

Somehow I believe describing the schema the following way makes mongoose to think that an array with a single object is expected:

```
var CartSchema = new Schema({
//...

requests: [{
        _id:false,
        type: String,   
        count: Number,  
        expiration: String
    }]

})
```

After a couple of tries, I found that replacing the previous one with an embedded schema works:

```
var RequestSchema = new Schema({
        _id:false,
        type: String,   
        count: Number,  
        expiration: String
    });

var CartSchema = new Schema({
//...

requests: [ RequestSchema ]

})
```